# Disk is write protected

Tags: dos, dosbox

I am running a DOS program on Linux using dosemu on Ubuntu.
The program uses floppy disk, mounted on A:

I am able to create files in the floppy disk using the command line in dosemu. But when the program tries to write something on the floppy drive it returns an error Disk is write protected.

Comment: Have you checked the small *Write Protect switch* in Floppy Drive?

Comment: Those things still exist?

Comment: Yeah I have checked the switch.

Comment: Even my dosemu is able to create files.

Comment: Sounds like the program has a bug in it, or has an edge case that dosemu doesn't handle well.